# Cocoa - Load resource from non-main bundles

Tags: macos, cocoa, resources, nsbundle

My application loads some custom bundles and it wants to use resources in these bundles.

It seems that it's impossible to get resources from main bundle instance, like [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:ofType:].

So I replace it with +[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:] and it works well. But it's quite inconvenient that the resource-loading code should know the bundle path for "inDirectory:". It won't work if bundles are moved to another paths.

Are there other methods to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to accomplish, but if you want to load a bundle resource without using the direct path to the bundle, you can use either `[NSBundle bundleForClass:]` or `[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:]`. Once you have a reference to the instance of the bundle you want, you can access its contents as follows:

```
NSBundle myBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.my.identifier"];
[myBundle pathForResource:@"myResource" ofType:@"type"];
```

If you want it to still be accurate even after the bundle has moved, that might be a trickier question. As the documentation states, "An NSBundle object represents a location in the file system...". If that location moves, the bundle instance will still look in the existing location. I think you will need to figure out another mechanism to determine if the bundle is moved and recreate your NSBundle instance from the new location.